# eBay GetOrders - Orders Older Than 90 Days

Tags: c#, ebay-api

When I use eBay's GetOrdersCall, can I pull orders older than 90 days? I set the dates to 10/1 to 10/3, however, I see no orders. My client is no longer able to see the orders in her eBay admin. Do I need to adjust my call to pull these orders?

Request:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
{
    if (getOrdersCall.Pagination != null && i > getOrdersCall.PaginationResult.TotalNumberOfPages)
        break;

    getOrdersCall.Pagination = new PaginationType() { PageNumber = i, PageNumberSpecified = true, EntriesPerPage = 50, EntriesPerPageSpecified = true };
    getOrdersCall.OrderRole = TradingRoleCodeType.Seller;
    getOrdersCall.OrderStatus = OrderStatusCodeType.All;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Settings.OrderStatus))
    {
        getOrdersCall.CreateTimeFrom = Settings.LastDownloadUtc;
        getOrdersCall.CreateTimeTo = Settings.LastDownloadUtcEnd;
    }
    else
    {
        getOrdersCall.ModTimeFrom = Settings.LastDownloadUtc;
        getOrdersCall.ModTimeTo = Settings.LastDownloadUtcEnd;
    }

    getOrdersCall.Execute();

    GetOrdersResponseType response = getOrdersCall.AbstractResponse as GetOrdersResponseType;

    if (response.Ack == AckCodeType.Success)
    {
        orders.AddRange(response.OrderArray);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot retrieve item's older than 90 days using this call.  See API documentation:

[eBay API GetOrders](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/getorders.html)

Most likely, you could retrieve this data through a different report.  I am looking into the possibility now.  Will post back.

***Edit***

Note: GetSellerTransactions is also limited to time periods within the last 90 days.

Comment: The documentation states you can't use a "date from" older than 90 days. "This value cannot be set back more than 90 days in the past, as this call cannot retrieve sales older than 90 days old."

Comment: Presuming you cannot enter a date more than 90 days in the past into "date from", you effectively cannot use that call to retrieve orders older than 90 days.  I reviewed the documentation for the GetSellerTransactions and after a brief review, did not see any restrictions on the date entered.  I'm not sure what your comment is referring to, as it seems that it correlates with what was stated in the post, in slightly different terms.

Comment: Just pointing out that the OP is asking to "pull orders older than 90 days". However GetSellerTransactions will return an error if you try to set the time filter before 90 days, hence it's not a viable answer. As far as I know it's not possible using any of eBay's API calls.

Comment: Ok.  I found what you are referring to finally!  You are correct, GetSellerTransactions does not allow information to be retrieved older than 90 days.  This answer is almost 18 months old so I'm not sure the condition of the API call when I wrote that answer =p  I will update the post accordingly.

Comment: It's just for the sake of anyone else searching for answer (like I was!)..

Comment: Might try the OrderReport call.  It has a date range filter, but I'm not seeing it defined in an input table in the API documentation unfortunately so I can't tell if it has a 90 day limit or not..